# How can I make Pandas convert a column which contains NaT from timedelta to datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have a pandas dataframe with a column which is of type `timedelta64[ns]`, and which I would like to convert ot `datetime64[ns]`.

The `pd.to_datetime()` function purports to do just that, and has worked in the past, but appears to fail now. I would assume this might be related to an API quirk which has gone beneath my radar. Currently it fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 724, in to_datetime
    cache_array = _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 152, in _maybe_cache
    cache_dates = convert_listlike(unique_dates, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 363, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    arg, _ = maybe_convert_dtype(arg, copy=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py", line 1916, in maybe_convert_dtype
    raise TypeError(f"dtype {data.dtype} cannot be converted to datetime64[ns]")
TypeError: dtype timedelta64[ns] cannot be converted to datetime64[ns]
```

## To try and reproduce, please use the MWE below:

```
wget https://chymera.eu/ppb/61ebad.csv
python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('61ebad.csv')
df['Animal_death_date'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Animal_death_date'], errors='coerce')
df['Animal_death_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Animal_death_date'], errors='coerce')
```

The error also occurs if I am using `errors='ignore'`.
For reference, I am using Pandas `1.0.1`.

Comment: Not sure what is logic here, how you need convert timedelta to datetime? Add some column filled by datetimes? Or add some scalar like `df['Animal_death_date'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Animal_death_date'], errors='coerce') +  pd.to_datetime('2000-01-01')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need convert timedeltas to datetime, add some start datetime:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://chymera.eu/ppb/61ebad.csv')
start = pd.to_datetime('2000-01-01')
df['Animal_death_date'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Animal_death_date'], errors='coerce') + start
print (df['Animal_death_date'] )
0                     NaT
1                     NaT
2                     NaT
3                     NaT
4                     NaT

843                   NaT
844                   NaT
845   2000-05-12 19:00:00
846   2000-05-12 19:00:00
847   2000-05-12 19:00:00
Name: Animal_death_date, Length: 848, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or add some column filled by datetimes:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://chymera.eu/ppb/61ebad.csv')
start = pd.to_datetime(df['FMRIMeasurement_date'])
df['Animal_death_date'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Animal_death_date'], errors='coerce') + start
print (df['Animal_death_date'] )
0                     NaT
1                     NaT
2                     NaT
3                     NaT
4                     NaT

843                   NaT
844                   NaT
845   2018-10-04 19:20:54
846   2018-10-04 19:20:54
847   2018-10-04 19:20:54
Name: Animal_death_date, Length: 848, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually think I also remembered what happened, namely that `.to_datetime()` used to automatically make datetimes relative to `1970-01-01`.

Comment: @TheChymera - yes, I think new version of pandas change this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a small correction: Your source column in question is also
a **text** column, but only **formatted** as *timedelta*.

To convert *Animal_death_date* column define the following function:

```
def myDateConv(tt):
    return pd.to_datetime('2020-' + tt, format='%Y-%j days %X.%f')\
        if len(tt) > 0 else np.nan
```

I assume that your dates are from this year, hence *2020* as the initial
part of the whole date string. If they are from other year, change this
prefix accordingly.

But apply this function as early as when you **read** the source file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('61ebad.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=['Treatment_start_date',
    'Treatment_end_date', 'FMRIMeasurement_date', 'OpenFieldTestMeasurement_date',
    'ForcedSwimTestMeasurement_date', 'CageStay_start_date', 'Cage_Treatment_start_date',
    'Cage_Treatment_end_date', 'SucrosePreferenceMeasurement_date', 'reference_date'],
    converters = { 'Animal_death_date': myDateConv })
```

Note additional parameters:

- `index_col` - to treat the initial column as the index,
- `parse_dates` - to convert "normally" formatted dates to *datetime*,
- `converters` - to apply the above function to the source of
  *Animal_death_date* column.

I think, this solution is simpler and more readable than individual conversion
of particular columns.